# What does the error "ERROR: index ‘product’: raw_hits: write error: 122070 of 262017 bytes written" mean in Sphinx?

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx, ultrasphinx

Some of my indexes appear to be failing during the nightly rebuild with this error:

```
ERROR: index ‘product’: raw_hits: write error: 122070 of 262017 bytes written
```

The only reference I can find on the internet is in some multibyte language that I can't read.  Has anyone experienced this error before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sphinx is getting an error from the operating system that it can't write the file.

It sounds like you're running out of hard drive space, or encountering some other disk error.

If you are sure these are not the case, try reducing the [max_iosize](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-max-iosize) in your configuration.

Comment: I had this error recently, too, because the size of the index exceeded the available disk space. When the indexer aborts the indexing, parts of the newly created index are deleted again. Thus you may get this error message although the "df" command says there is enough free disk space.